# GROUP_CONCAT в Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

как реализовать

```
GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.`name` ORDER BY cp.`level` SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS `name`
```

в postgres?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.regionPathRepository.createQueryBuilder('rp')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('regions', 'r',"rp.region_id = r.id")
      .leftJoinAndSelect('regions', 'r2', 'rp.region_id = r2.id')
      .select([
        'rp.region_id as "regionId"',
        'r2.isPublished as "isPublished"'
      ])
      .addSelect('ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(r2.title ORDER BY rp.level ASC), \'>>\') as name')
      .groupBy('rp.region_id')
      .addGroupBy('r2.isPublished')
```